href attribute not working and not showing the url in VF email template
I have a simple vf email template in which I have a vf component called. In the component i'm trying to add a url using anchor tag and href but when the test email comes out the value is not getting displayed. I tried to add the same in the template itself and still no luck. The url is returning a page when I paste it in browser. But the url is still not displaying in the email nor in template preview.
Added below in VF email template & VF component. Able to print Guidelines but not the link.
<p> <strong> Guidelines: </strong></p><br></br>
    <p>  <a href="myLink" ></a>  <p>

When I inspect in the mail I see an originalsrc tag showing my url as below but it is blank in the email:

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Did you try: <p> <strong> Guidelines: </strong></p><br></br>     <p>  <a href="myLink" >Click here</a>  <p> ?

This is because in your anchor tag (<a>), you did not include any text between them, hence it is empty.
For example
<!-- openTheLink will be a clickable url -->
<a href="myLink">openTheLink</a>

vs
<!-- No content -->
<a href="myLink"></a>

Which would not display anything. You can easily test this W3 school playground.
To look into what I am saying you can modify the code in the playground, to this and click "Run".
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The a href attribute</h1>

<!--No content in anchor tag, hence nothing will show -->
<p>NO content in anchor tag URL: <a href="https://www.w3schools.com"></a></p> 

<!--Has content in anchor tag -->
<p>Has content: <a href="tag_a.asp">The a tag</a></p>

</body>
</html>


You can refer to the image below as well,

